# about optimizing for-in statement

Tags: javascript, optimization

I read an article named Optimization killers, and in [5.2.3. The object contains enumerable array indices](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#523-the-object-contains-enumerable-array-indices), It says :

> Workaround: Always use Object.keys and iterate over the array with for loop. If you truly need all properties from entire prototype chain, make an isolated helper function:

```
function inheritedKeys(obj) {
    var ret = [];
    for(var key in obj) {
        ret.push(key);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I don't understand what it means.
In the above code, there is still a `for...in`, so function inheritedKeys can't be optimized, how can it be an isolated helper function?

Answer (score 1):

That's just an example on how to get keys from an object doing it with the for in loop. 
He actually tells you that in order to make it faster you should use Object.keys when you want to get keys of an object.

Here's the test performance.
http://jsperf.com/forintest

So DON'T use this to retrieve object keys

```
function inheritedKeys(obj) {
    var ret = [];
    for(var key in obj) {
        ret.push(key);
    }
    return ret;
}
var myobject= {"1":"a","2":"b"};
var calculation = inheritedKeys(myobject);
```

Use this instead it's more clean simple to read and faster

```
var myobject= {"1":"a","2":"b"};
var calculation = Object.keys(myobject);
```

---

Here's a test comparing for in using with array and a normal for loop.

http://jsperf.com/forinarray

You can see that the for loop is way faster.

DON'T use this

```
function iteratesOverArray() {
    var arr = [1, 2, 3];
    var newArr = [];
    for (var index in arr) {
       newArr.push(index);
    }
    return newArr;
}
var arr = iteratesOverArray();
```

Use this instead

```
function iteratesOverArray() {
    var arr = [1, 2, 3];
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i=0,l=arr.length-1;i<=l;i++) {
       newArr.push(i);
    }
    return newArr;
}
var arr = iteratesOverArray();
```

Comment: I searched Object.keys(), and it says: The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys So Object.keys can't enumerate properties in the prototype chain. So the article says "If you truly need all properties from entire prototype chain, make an isolated helper function", but that function can't be optimized...

Comment: Object.keys does not enumerate it only retrieves the keys. If you want enumeration you would still have to iterate over them. (I wrote enumerate i meant retrieve in my example) You could also do something magic like Object.keys(Object.keys(myobject));Because object keys returns an array it than get's the indexes from the array returned.

Comment: I did the test again updated http://jsperf.com/forinarray
and normal for loop is still the best solution.